# Pixlr on Wine Need Help

Tags: wine

Any suggestions on how to get this Pixlr program to work on Wine.
Got this error.
[image]

Comment: I have not found any reports of that program working successfully under WINE. However, there is an online version at https://pixlr.com/

Comment: Just use GIMP...

Comment: Gimp is not easy to add two pictures together to make one collage.  To even add text and and resize it easily..like with a mouse..(I have no idea why it is so difficult and has not been made easier)